# wp_editor in custom post type is not saving formatted text like bold, italic etc

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, editor, visual-editor

My custom post type has 5 custom meta boxes which use `wp_editor`. Visually I can format the content but when saved, all the formatting is gone.

For example I made a portion of my content **bold**, but when I save / update, the formatting is no longer there both in front end and back end (when I go back to edit the same post).

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Maybe your save function strips the HTML tags. What's your metabox code?

Comment: You nailed it!! :)